# setOnClickListener calls the last instance of class

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

i have a calendar with multiple instances of CalendarCell, each cell has a listener that is bound to it in the constructor function, but when i click a cell, i get the event of the last cell created
here is my class

```
public class CalendarCell extends TextView{
  public String date;
  public CalendarCell(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Log",CalendarCell.this.date);                
        }
    });
}
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: Are you sure your indexing is right? As in, you are actually getting the `CalendarCell` you think you are getting?

Comment: i didn't understand your question...
i am clicking on the cell i want in the calendar, so i think i'm getting the right cell (if this is what you meant).

Comment: It's just that one explanation could be you are clicking on a cell but getting the cell before. I don't know how you are selecting cells or what your arrays are like but that's my guess!

Comment: i fixed it by using CalendarCell.this.setOnClickListener instead of this.setOnClickListener. I dont know exactly why it is working, i'm hoping that someone could explain this to me